# Runtime error '424' object required on vba macro

Tags: html, vba, runtime-error, getelementbyid

I am receiving a

> '424 runtime error; object required'

on my excel macro when it comes to the code posted below. I am trying to set the contents of an html userform to the strings I have parsed out of a text document.

```
Set wb = WB1.document
Set wb.getElementById("booktitle").Value = book
```

I've also tried:

```
Set wb = WB1.document

With wb
    .getElementById("booktitle").Value = book
End With
```

this is my HTML:

```
 <div class="section"><span>1</span>Book</div>
 <div class="inner-wrap">
     <label>Full Book Title <input id="booktitle" type="text" name="bookTitle" /></label>
```

WB1 is my userform webbrowser

Comment: What's the declaration (Dim) of wb? What's WB1?

Comment: Is the error occuring on the first line or the second?

Comment: this line certainly doesn't make sense `Set wb.getElementById("booktitle").Value = book`. The `.Value` of something won't be an object, so remove the `Set` keyword (I can see you've tried that - so this is confirmation!)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options when dealing with *properties*. `.Value` *is* a property, but you are using the `Set` command, which is reserved for *objects*.

You can **set** the object to a variable, such as:

```
Dim oBookTitle As Object
Set oBookTitle = wb.getElementById("booktitle")
oBookTitle.Value = book
```

`getElementByID()` returns an object --- `.Value` returns or sets the value *of the object* (it's a property).

Or you can simply use the property directly:

```
wb.getElementById("booktitle").Value = book
```

---

> *"Yes I changed it to try set earlier in the day when I originally had what you posted, it does not work with or without set."* – [bella98789](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7100195/bella98789)

I don't see a "Value" in the HTML code. You can try `.innerText` or `.outerText` instead of `.Value` and see if that resolves your issue.

Also, if you are not waiting for your webpage to load completely, then your object won't be available. Add this line for debugging purposes:

```
If wb.getElementById("booktitle") Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Obj not set"
```

---

Comment: Yes I changed it to try set earlier in the day when I originally had what you posted, it does not work with or without set.

Comment: I don't believe the issue to be with .value or .innertext, both work because I can iterate through debug and the result comes out with the userform filled out. I just can't tell what else would cause this error

Comment: @bella98789 did you see my 2nd update? Add the `If` statement and see if the msgbox shows or not.

Comment: Then can you specify which line exactly raises the error? Because from what you are saying, the object is set because it didn't prompt the msgbox. The VBE will stop and highlight in yellow the line causing the error.

Comment: wb.getElementById("booktitle").Value = book. this is the line causing the runtime error. book is a string previously parsed from a text document while wb is set from the line in my post

Comment: Where did you declare `book`? Where does `book` receive its value?